# Функция для оборачивания данных XML тегами

Tags: golang

Вот хочу сделать функцию для оборачивания данных тегами в XML, т.е. в функцию передаётся переменная которая оборачивается в разные теги в зависимости от типа переменной, в NodeJS я бы определял тип через TypeOf, в С++ перезагрузил бы функцию, а как это можно сделать на Golang?
Проблема в том что ф-ция принимает типизированную переменную, а перезагрузки как в С++ нет.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/?

Comment: Через [reflect.TypeOf](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf)?

Comment: Уточнил суть вопроса

Comment: штатаня библиотека не подходит, там специфичный XML-RPC, иначе использовал бы её

Comment: Так определите интерфейс и соотв. методы для каждого типа. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется тс имел ввиду это:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func wrap(tag, val string) string {
    res := "<" + tag + ">" + val + "</" + tag + ">"
    return res
}

func xmlize(i interface{}) (string, error) {
    switch val := i.(type) {
    case string:
        return wrap("string", val), nil
    case int, int32, int64, int8, int16, uint, uint32, uint64, uint8, uint16:
        return wrap("integer", fmt.Sprintf("%d", val)), nil
    case float32, float64:
        return wrap("float", fmt.Sprintf("%f", val)), nil
    }

    return "", fmt.Errorf("Unknown type")
}

func main() {
    s, _ := xmlize("some text value")
    fmt.Println(s)
    s, _ = xmlize(10)
    fmt.Println(s)
    s, _ = xmlize(10.20)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nYP7OfusU6T

Comment: Наверное да, спасибо за ответ, просто прочитал что перезагрузки в Go нет и это немножечко сбило с толку.